# Visual Studio dialog: You are renaming a script file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

We keep getting the following dialog in Visual Studio when renaming files:
[image]

While I admire the effort of this option it simple doesn't work as intended and so we would like to disable this option.

My Google-fu hasn't been strong enough, does anybody know how to disable (or what extension produces) this option?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on my machine by going to `Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions` then uncheck the `Prompt for symbolic renaming when renaming files` checkbox.